# LiveData does not emit with FirebaseAuth addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

This is my first experience with LiveData. So please pardon me if I did anything wrong.

I set the breakpoint at LoginVM and I found that the logIn function which returns a LiveData does not called even the authentication was success and postValue are called to set the data. I don't understand why.

**UserRemoteRepository.kt**

```
override fun signIn(email: String, password: String): LiveData<FirebaseUser> {
    val loggedInUser: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser> = MutableLiveData()

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    loggedInUser.postValue(mAuth.currentUser)
                }
            }

    return loggedInUser
}
```

**LoginVM.kt**

```
fun login() = Transformations.map(UserRemoteRepository.signIn(email.get().toString(), password.get().toString())) {
    it
}
```

**LoginFrag.kt**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val viewModel = viewDataBinding.viewmodel

    viewModel?.login()?.observe(this.activity, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG, it?.email)
    })
}
```